# How to load font for emacs on Arch Linux?

Tags: init-file, fonts, error

I want to use a custom font for emacs on arch linux.
Therefore, I installed the package `ttc-iosevka`.

Then I added the following line to my init.el:

```
(set-frame-font "/usr/share/fonts/TTF/iosevka-medium.ttc")
```

This file however, can't get loaded.. Running emacs with `--debug-init`:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Font not available")
```

How do I add the font properly? I've never done this and I couldn't find anything on the Internet.

Comment: If you start up `M-x ielm` and do `(x-list-fonts "*")` you'll see a list of valid strings you can pass to `set-frame-font`.

Comment: @g-gundam Great! Is there a way to filter my particular string out? Or in other words. How do I add a font to the list?

Comment: I regret telling you about x-list-fonts, because there's an easier way to do it.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the font is installed correctly, you can just pass in the name of the font to `set-frame-font`.

```lisp
(set-frame-font "Iosevka Fixed")

;; You can also give it a size.
(set-frame-font "Iosevka Fixed 11")
```

You can see a list of font names from the command line by running:

```bash
# simple
fc-list
# better formatting and sorted
fc-list --format="%{family[0]}\n" | sort | uniq
```

Local font installation in Linux is really easy too.

- Copy the font to `~/.local/share/fonts`
- Run `fc-cache -fv`

It sounds like you installed it from a package which is fine too.

Comment: Great! This worked. :)

Comment: I figured this out by doing `C-h f set-frame-font` and reading the docs and then reading the source of the function.  I didn't know how to do it before you asked, but I knew how to ask emacs for clues.  (I've changed fonts before, but it's been a while, so I didn't remember the details.)

Comment: Nice to know. I'm new to emacs and so knowing this is brilliant :)